# NHibernate select column with SqlFunction, group by same criteria

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I need to query for a count based on each day as well as group by the same criteria. The generated query should look similar to

```
select SendTo, dateadd(dd,
                 0,
                 datediff(dd,
                          0,
                          WorkToBeginDate))
from Locates
group by SendTo, dateadd(dd,
                 0,
                 datediff(dd,
                          0,
                          WorkToBeginDate))
```

I'm currently using the query below but it does not group by the `date`.

```
var dateGroupBy = Projections.SqlFunction("date", NHibernateUtil.Date,
    Projections.Group<Domain.Locate>(g => g.WorkToBeginDate));

var stats = 
    _session.QueryOver<Domain.Locate>()
    .SelectList(x => x
        .SelectGroup(xx => xx.SendTo).WithAlias(() => statsDto.SentTo)
        .SelectCount(xx => xx.LocateId).WithAlias(() => statsDto.Count)
        .Select(dateGroupBy)
        .WithAlias(() => statsDto.DueDate))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StatsDto>())
    .List<StatsDto>();
```

Executing this query yields

```
SELECT   this_.SendTo                             as y0_,
         count(this_.LocateId)                    as y1_,
         dateadd(dd,
                 0,
                 datediff(dd,
                          0,
                          this_.WorkToBeginDate)) as y2_
FROM     Locates this_
GROUP BY this_.SendTo,
         this_.WorkToBeginDate
```

I'm assuming it's because I'm using `Select` and not `SelectGroup` in my projections. I have tried `.SelectGroup(xx => new SqlFunctionProjection("date", NHibernateUtil.Date, Projections.Group<Domain.Locate>(g => g.WorkToBeginDate)))`, however this gives me `Could not determine member from new SqlFunctionProjection("date", NHibernateUtil.Date, new [] {Group(g => Convert(g.WorkToBeginDate))})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest the dateGroupBy value with another `Projections.Group` method.

```
var dateGroupBy = Projections.Group(Projections.SqlFunction("date", NHibernateUtil.Date,
Projections.Group<Domain.Locate>(g => g.WorkToBeginDate)));
```

That should give you the desired results. :)